# how to assign value directly to kendo data-bind

Tags: kendo-ui

how to assign value directly to kendo data-bind

here is the code

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="add-new-user-template">
<li>
    <a class="user-result">
        <span class="row-name">Create New User</span>
        <br/>
        <input type="hidden" class="hf-user-role-id" data-bind="value: 0"/>
        <input type="hidden" class="row-party-id" data-bind="value: "/>
            </a>
</li>
</script>
```

hav to set first input field value to 0 and second to empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I don't really know if I understood what you try to achieve, but if you want to set `static` values, why not just doing `<input type="hidden" name="user-id" value="0" class="hf-user-role-id" />` since there is (in my opinion) no sense of `binding` static values.
The `data-bind` attribute needs a variable or some JSON to be bound to not a static value.

Cheers

Comment: I was just refering to your first first input field

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to do this:

```
$('.hf-user-role-id').attr('data-bind', "value: 0");
$('.row-party-id').attr('data-bind', "value:");
```

The jquery attribute method allows you to change the values of an attribute. 
If you are using kendo ui then you will almost certainly have included jquery.